# Python in range within list

Tags: python

The concept of my problem is to identify a letter for a random number.

`ra_list` holds the random float numbers.

`e_list` holds the letter and the range.

The current code, identifies string matching and randomises between B and C letters as they have the same value.

```
 ra_list = [6, 7, 7]
 e_list = [(6, 'A'), (7, 'B'), (7, 'C'), (8, 'E')]

 test_dict = {}

 for key,val in e_list:
      test_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(val)

 import random
 for i in ra_list:
       cate = random.choice(test_dict.get(i,[0]))


       if cate != 0:  
           print i,cate
```

However, my problem is that I have float numbers in `ra_list` and would like to implement ranges - I have very little python experience.  How would one manipulate the current code and solve the issue of in range?  `e_list` will always be in ascending order.  For example:

```
 ra_list = [6.25, 7.5, 7.6]
 e_list = [(6, 'A'), (7.4, 'B'), (7.4, 'C'), (7.7, 'E')]
 output = (6.25, A), (7.5, B or C), (7.6, B or C)
```

Values from `ra_list` less than the first value of `e_list` should get `A` and values greater than the last value should be `E`.

Comment: You want the code to output 'B or C', or it doesn't matter which is it?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's B or C as they have the same values.  The code I currently have will produce either B or C, and if E was 7, it'd iterate through B,C or E too.  It's the range I'm struggling with.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by range here, and what are you trying to accomplish, sorry.

Comment: from my example, the first element in ra_list is 6.25, it's letter would therefore be A as its between the values of A(6) and B(7.4).

Comment: int(6.25)=6 use that for lookup.

Comment: @karafka This won't work, because the ranges could be wider - e.g. A(6), B(8) and lookup of a value int(7.25) would fail, because there would be no key 7 in the dictionary.

Comment: can the values in ra_list be less than or greater than  those in e_list? Also e_list seems to be ascending not descending

Comment: yes, values in ra_list can be greater than the highest number in e_list, and therefore should be allocated the highest letter.  plus, my bad about the e_list!

Comment: What should happen if `7.7` is in r_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One naive approach would be to create a sorted list of the dictionary keys and find the one that one with the maximum value while being smaller than the input float.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import random

ra_list = [5, 6.25, 7.5, 7.6]
e_list = [(6, 'A'), (7.4, 'B'), (7.4, 'C'), (7.7, 'E')]

test_dict = OrderedDict()

for key,val in e_list:
    test_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(val)

key_list = list(test_dict.keys())
min_key = key_list[0]

for i in ra_list:
    max_key = min_key
    for key in key_list:
        if i >= key:
            max_key = key
        else:
            break
    cate = random.choice(test_dict.get(max_key))

    print( i,cate)
```

This is more computational complex than converting the input float to an integer, but has the benefit that you can add floats to your (number, letter) pairs.

EDIT 2:
Updated original answer according to comments.

Comment: it seems to be producing 0 for each element in the list?

Comment: That is weird, my output matches the op's requirement:
`6.25 A
7.5 B
7.6 B`. Which version of python do you use?

Comment: It fails for value in ra_list less than the smallest value in e_list, `ra_list = [5, 6.25, 7.5, 7.6,9]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham agreed. Just noticed this too.  How would this be implemented from 0?

Comment: It does not print anything for 5, this is correct. However, that state is undefined based on my understanding of the op's problem. However, if the requirement is to match `5` in this case to the smallest value in the dict, this can easily be done by changing `max_key = None` to `max_key = sorted(test_dict.keys())[0]`

Comment: Why are you  repeatedly sorting the list for every element in ra_list and also calling .keys every time?

Comment: I oversaw that tbh. Is it okay, if I update my code accordingly?

Comment: yep, sort one with `sorted(test_dict)` or better again use an OrderedDict as the data is already ordered

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm running into an issue where it doesn't seem to be iterating over e_list. Every element in ra_list seems to always e the first letter in e_list, when they shouldnt.  Output is like so ((44.8,), 0.43) ((56.3,), 0.43) when e_list = [(0.43,"a"), (0.63, "b")]

Comment: @HndrkMkt ra_list = [(44.8, 'hi'),(56.3, 'bye')] e_list = [(0.43, 'a'), (0.63, 'b')] and I'm using exactly the same code as what you provided - thankyou btw.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: e_list is relatively large with 2000 elements.

Comment: Well, you are using tuples in ra_list now instead of floats. You need to use the tuples first value to create the mapping. You could say `ra_key = i[0]` as first statement in `for i in ra_list` and then check for `if ra_key >= key:`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
In [1]: e_list = [(6, 'A'), (7, 'B'), (7, 'C'), (8, 'E')]

In [2]: import random

In [3]: from collections import OrderedDict 

In [4]: choices_dict = OrderedDict()

In [5]: for x in e_list:
            ra = x[0]
            e = x[1]
            if ra in choices_dict:
                choices_dict[ra].append(e)  
            else:
                choices_dict[ra] = [e]

In [6]: choices_dict
Out [6]: OrderedDict([(6, ['A']), (7, ['B', 'C']), (8, ['E'])])
```

`choices_dict` is a dictionary containing the limit and the letter.

We create a function `get_e_value` which will give us the value of `e` for a given `ra`.

If the value lies inside a range, then a random letter out of letters list from the lower limit is returned from the `choices_dict`. Else, the letter for highest range is returned.

```
In [7]: def get_e_value(my_number):                  
            limits = choices_dict.keys()
            limits_count = len(limits)
            for x in range(limits_count):
                if (my_number <= limits[x]) or (x!= limits_count-1 and my_number<limits[x+1]): # check if number lies between a range
                    choices = choices_dict[limits[x]]
                    return random.choice(choices)               

            last_key = limits[-1] # number is beyond range
            return random.choice(choices_dict[last_key]) # return largest range letter  

In [8]: ra_list = [1.3, 2.5, 5, 6.3, 7.5, 8.5]

In [9]: final_output = [(x, get_e_value(x)) for x in ra_list] 

In [10]: final_output
Out [10]: [(1.3, 'A'), (2.5, 'A'), (5, 'A'), (6.3, 'A'), (7.5, 'C'), (8.5, 'E')]
```

Comment: 7.5 should be B or C not E

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep! You are right. Updated the ans.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bisect module using the first element from each sub tuple as the key to bisect which will give you a  running time that is `O(N log N)` as opposed to the quadratic:

```
from bisect import bisect
from random import choice

def pair(l, l2):
    # use first element from each tuple as the key
    keys = [r[0] for r in l2]
    for i in l:
        # find the index i would go in keys to  keep order
        ind = bisect(keys, i)
        # make sure we don't wrap araound i.e 0 to -1
        # and don't fall of the end
        ind = ind - 1 if ind > 0 else ind
        yield (i, e_list[ind][1])
```

output:

```
In [32]: ra_list = [5.5, 6.25, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7,9.0]

In [33]: e_list = [(6, 'A'), (7.4, 'B'), (7.4, 'C'), (7.7, 'E')]

In [34]: list(pair(ra_list,  e_list))
Out[34]: [(5.5, 'A'), (6.25, 'A'), (7.5, 'C'), (7.6, 'C'), (7.7, 'E'), (9.0, 'E')]
```

If you really want a random choice for repeated values, the logic is exactly the same, you just need to group them in a dict again and check if the length of the value/list for each corresponding key contains more than a single element or not, if it does randomly choose one:

```
def pair(l, l2):
    dct = {}
    for a, b in l2:
        dct.setdefault(a, []).append(b)
    keys = [r[0] for r in l2]
    for i in l:
        ind = bisect(keys, i)
        print(ind,i)
        ind = ind - 1 if 0 < ind else ind
        val = dct[e_list[ind][0]]
        yield ((i, val[0]) if len(val) == 1 else (i, choice(val)))
```

Output:

```
In [63]: ra_list = [5.5, 6.25, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 9.0]    
In [64]: e_list = [(6, 'A'), (7.4, 'B'), (7.4, 'C'), (7.7, 'E'), (7.7, "F")]

In [65]: print(list(pair(ra_list,  e_list)))
[(5.5, 'A'), (6.25, 'A'), (7.5, 'C'), (7.6, 'C'), (7.7, 'F'), (7.8, 'F'), (9.0, 'E')]

In [66]: print(list(pair(ra_list,  e_list)))
[(5.5, 'A'), (6.25, 'A'), (7.5, 'B'), (7.6, 'C'), (7.7, 'F'), (7.8, 'F'), (9.0, 'E')]

In [67]: print(list(pair(ra_list,  e_list)))
[(5.5, 'A'), (6.25, 'A'), (7.5, 'B'), (7.6, 'B'), (7.7, 'F'), (7.8, 'F'), (9.0, 'F')]

In [68]: print(list(pair(ra_list,  e_list)))
[(5.5, 'A'), (6.25, 'A'), (7.5, 'C'), (7.6, 'B'), (7.7, 'F'), (7.8, 'F'), (9.0, 'E')]

In [69]: print(list(pair(ra_list,  e_list)))
[(5.5, 'A'), (6.25, 'A'), (7.5, 'C'), (7.6, 'C'), (7.7, 'E'), (7.8, 'F'), (9.0, 'E')]
```

Not sure if an exact match appears what should happen, if it does like `7.7` above it will use the corresponding value, if it should be something else then it will still only take constant work so the runtime will stay at `N log N`